# Condition in React with data Fetch

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, next.js, conditional-statements, fetch-api

I have a problem: i want to show on the table just the "nameProcesso and "id" that has in the file json the attribute "errore = true".

I did the data fetch and now i can't put the condition inside my function

Can someone help me?

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Fetch() {
  'use client';
  const [appState, setAppState] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    let Errore = false;
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get(
        'https://run.mocky.io/v3/f3bf41f3-c60a-47f8-9386-243989bead65'
      );
      
      const string = '[' + response.data + ']';
      if (!Errore) {
      setAppState(JSON.parse(string));
    }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const nameProcesso = (
    <ul>
      {appState.map((item) => {
        switch(item){
            case Errore || Errore.type === true: 
            return <p> {item.nameProcesso}</p>,<p> {item.id}</p>;
            default:
                return null;
        }
      } 
      )}
    </ul>
  );

    return (
         
        <table>
        <thead> 
        <tr>
        <th className={styles.colonnaErrori}>LISTA DEI PROCESSI IN ERRORE </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        
        <tbody >   
        <tr className={styles.righeErrori}>
              <td> {nameProcesso} </td>    
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable Errore in your code is set to false and never updated. This makes the condition case Errore || Errore.type === true always evaluate to false.

I don't think the switch statement is suitable for this kind of comparison, so, try an if statement instead.

Here's a version that assumes that each item in your JSON data has a top-level "errore" attribute:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Fetch() {
  const [appState, setAppState] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get(
        'https://run.mocky.io/v3/f3bf41f3-c60a-47f8-9386-243989bead65'
      );
      const string = '[' + response.data + ']';
      setAppState(JSON.parse(string));
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const filteredItems = appState.filter(item => item.errore === true);

  const nameProcesso = (
    <ul>
      {filteredItems.map((item, index) => (
        <li key={index}>
          <p>{item.nameProcesso}</p>
          <p>{item.id}</p>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );

  return (
    <table>
      <thead> 
        <tr>
          <th className={styles.colonnaErrori}>LISTA DEI PROCESSI IN ERRORE</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr className={styles.righeErrori}>
          <td>{nameProcesso}</td>    
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

This version uses a Array.prototype.filter() method to create a new array that contains only the items where "errore" is true. Then, it maps over this new array to generate the list items.

Comment: It's work thankyou so much. How is gonna work if i want to use the operator IF inside here? Beacuse i tried to use it but doesn't work.

Comment: Another question: If i want to order all the data by the chronological order (by the attribute "Giorno" in json) how can i do? I tried with SORT() but doesn't work. in wich part of the code i need to put?

Answer (score 0):

attribute. This step should be performed before filtering or displaying the data.

You can adjust your ***useEffect*** and ***filteredItems***

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(
      'https://run.mocky.io/v3/f3bf41f3-c60a-47f8-9386-243989bead65'
    );
    const string = '[' + response.data + ']';
    const parsedData = JSON.parse(string);

    // Sort the data by "Giorno"
    const sortedData = parsedData.sort((a, b) => {
      return new Date(a.Giorno) - new Date(b.Giorno);
    });

    setAppState(sortedData);
  };
  fetchData();
}, []);

const filteredItems = appState.filter(item => item.errore === true);
```

If you want to display only the items with the attribute "errore = true" in your table, you can an ***if*** condition within the .map() function. However, since you're already using the .filter() method to create a filteredItems array, this isn't strictly necessary for your specific use case. The filteredItems array should already contain only the items where "errore" is true, thanks to this line:

```
const filteredItems = appState.filter(item => item.errore === true);
```